# Leaflet show or hide layers WFS cql_filter

Tags: leaflet, javascript, wfs, cql-filter

I use the library Leaflet-WFST. So I have both WMS and WFS layers. With WMS, everything is simple there is `cql_filter`. I am writing a code where `cql_filter` is applied when clicking on the checkbox, here is the code:

```
$("#s23").click(function () {
  if ($("#s23").is(":checked")) {
    if (
      layer.wmsParams.cql_filter != "" &&
      layer.wmsParams.cql_filter.includes("layer_id=23") == false
    ) {
      layer.setParams({
        cql_filter: layer.wmsParams.cql_filter + " OR layer_id=23",
      });
    } else layer.setParams({ cql_filter: "layer_id=23" });
    layer.setOpacity(1);
  } else if (layer.wmsParams.cql_filter.includes(" OR layer_id=23") == true) {
    l_edit = layer.wmsParams.cql_filter.replace(" OR layer_id=23", "");
    layer.setParams({ cql_filter: l_edit });
  } else if (layer.wmsParams.cql_filter.includes("layer_id=23 OR ") == true) {
    l_edit = layer.wmsParams.cql_filter.replace("layer_id=23 OR ", "");
    layer.setParams({ cql_filter: l_edit });
  } else layer.setParams({ cql_filter: "" });
  console.log(layer.wmsParams.cql_filter);
});

$("#s29").click(function () {
  if ($("#s29").is(":checked")) {
    console.log(layer);
    if (
      layer.wmsParams.cql_filter != "" &&
      layer.wmsParams.cql_filter.includes("layer_id=29") == false
    )
      layer.setParams({
        cql_filter: layer.wmsParams.cql_filter + " OR layer_id=29",
      });
    else layer.setParams({ cql_filter: "layer_id=29" });
    layer.setOpacity(1);
    console.log(layer.wmsParams.cql_filter);
  } else if (layer.wmsParams.cql_filter.includes(" OR layer_id=29") == true) {
    l_edit = layer.wmsParams.cql_filter.replace(" OR layer_id=29", "");
    layer.setParams({ cql_filter: l_edit });
  } else if (layer.wmsParams.cql_filter.includes("layer_id=29 OR ") == true) {
    l_edit = layer.wmsParams.cql_filter.replace("layer_id=29 OR ", "");
    layer.setParams({ cql_filter: l_edit });
  } else layer.setParams({ cql_filter: "" });
  console.log(layer.wmsParams.cql_filter);
});
```

Here, if `cql_filter` is added when the checkbox is clicked, if it is empty, then `cql_filter: 'layer_id=23'` is triggered, and if there is something in `cql_filter`, then `cql_filter: layer.wmsParams.cql_filter + ' OR layer_id=23'` also if the checkbox was cleared, then this `layer_id` is removed from `cql_filter`.

I can use this code:

```
var layer_23 = new L.Filter.EQ("layer_id", 23);
//var OR = new L.Filter.Or(layer.options.filter, layer_23);
layer.options.filter = layer_23;
layer.loadFeatures(layer_23);
```

To add a new filter, but I don't know how I can remove or edit it.

The question is, how can the same thing be done?

Comment: Store individual filter statements in an array, as `let arr = ['layer_id=10', 'layer_id=20']`, and leverage [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) as in `arr.join(' OR ')`. Add/remove elements from that array as needed, then `join()` it just before passing it as the CQL filter.

Comment: Which WFST Leaflet plugin are you using? This plugin https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet-WFST does not specify filters the way desrcibed above.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Why did you edit out code where filter was specified in the form `L.Filter.EQ('layer_id', 23)`? That's the form used by plugin https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet-WFST.

Comment: Ooops, my copy-paste-fu failed me earlier today :-(

Comment: I have a working WMS, I have problems with WFS, I wrote the WMS code as an example to do the same as WFS, I can't filter WFS correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply new filter to WFS layer created with [Leaflet-WFST](https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet-WFST) plugin, you have to use layers `.loadFeatures(filter)` method, where parameter `filter` is the new filter. Since plugin WFS layer is extension of Leaflet `L.layerGroup` layer, previous features must first be cleared with `.clearLayer()` method.

So if you initially have WFS layer with `filter1` like this:

```
var filter1 = new L.Filter.EQ('landuse', 'reservoir');

var wfs = new L.WFS({
  url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wfs?service=WF',
  typeNS: 'osm',
  typeName: 'water_areas',
  crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
  geometryField: 'the_geom',
  filter: filter1,
  style: {
    color: 'blue',
    weight: 2
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

then you apply new filter `filter2` like this:

```
var filter2 = L.Filter.Or(filter1, new L.Filter.EQ('waterway', 'riverbank'));

wfs.clearLayers();
wfs.loadFeatures(filter2);
```